# Transaction traking in Shopify stopped worked

Tags: google-analytics, shopify

I recently connected the Google Channel application (Google and YouTube) to my store Shopify, entered the Google Analytics 4 ID and everything worked great. Purchases flowed into analytics and other e-commerce events.
But in recent days, since about May 26, 2023, for some reason, purchases have ceased to be tracked. However, I didn't change any settings.
Did someone face similar?